# dbus-daemon Activated service 'org.freedesktop.Notifications' failed: Process org.freedesktop.Notifications exited with status 1

Tags: linux, arch-linux, systemd, notifications, manjaro

I keep having problems with my notifications not loading in i3 on Manjaro.

This cause weird issues with the notification icons not working.
Like network manager doesn't show its menu when I click on it.
Discord with randomly hang, or my session will freeze at random times.

I see the following:

```
journalctl -b | grep -i notification
Jul 10 08:28:01 aaron-lpt dbus-daemon[817]: [system] Service file "/usr/share/dbus-1/system-services/org.freedesktop.Notification.service" should have been named "org.freedesktop.Notifications.service" and will not work with system bus activation
Jul 10 08:29:08 aaron-lpt dbus-daemon[1520]: [session uid=1000 pid=1520] Activating service name='org.freedesktop.Notifications' requested by ':1.14' (uid=1000 pid=1581 comm="xfce4-power-manager ")
Jul 10 08:30:08 aaron-lpt plasma_waitforname[1652]: org.kde.knotifications: WaitForName: Service was not registered within timeout
Jul 10 08:30:08 aaron-lpt dbus-daemon[1520]: [session uid=1000 pid=1520] Activated service 'org.freedesktop.Notifications' failed: Process org.freedesktop.Notifications exited with status 1
Jul 10 08:30:08 aaron-lpt dbus-daemon[1520]: [session uid=1000 pid=1520] Activating service name='org.freedesktop.Notifications' requested by ':1.11' (uid=1000 pid=1553 comm="nm-applet ")
Jul 10 08:31:08 aaron-lpt plasma_waitforname[4024]: org.kde.knotifications: WaitForName: Service was not registered within timeout
Jul 10 08:31:08 aaron-lpt dbus-daemon[1520]: [session uid=1000 pid=1520] Activated service 'org.freedesktop.Notifications' failed: Process org.freedesktop.Notifications exited with status 1
Jul 10 09:29:12 aaron-lpt dbus-daemon[1520]: [session uid=1000 pid=1520] Activating service name='org.freedesktop.Notifications' requested by ':1.4' (uid=1000 pid=1558 comm="pamac-tray ")
Jul 10 09:30:13 aaron-lpt plasma_waitforname[10402]: org.kde.knotifications: WaitForName: Service was not registered within timeout
Jul 10 09:30:13 aaron-lpt dbus-daemon[1520]: [session uid=1000 pid=1520] Activated service 'org.freedesktop.Notifications' failed: Process org.freedesktop.Notifications exited with status 1
Jul 10 09:39:26 aaron-lpt dbus-daemon[1520]: [session uid=1000 pid=1520] Activating service name='org.freedesktop.Notifications' requested by ':1.268' (uid=1000 pid=9047 comm="/opt/discord/Discord ")
Jul 10 09:40:27 aaron-lpt plasma_waitforname[11135]: org.kde.knotifications: WaitForName: Service was not registered within timeout
Jul 10 09:40:27 aaron-lpt dbus-daemon[1520]: [session uid=1000 pid=1520] Activated service 'org.freedesktop.Notifications' failed: Process org.freedesktop.Notifications exited with status 1
Jul 10 09:40:27 aaron-lpt dbus-daemon[1520]: [session uid=1000 pid=1520] Activating service name='org.freedesktop.Notifications' requested by ':1.268' (uid=1000 pid=9047 comm="/opt/discord/Discord ")
Jul 10 09:40:38 aaron-lpt systemd[1495]: Starting XFCE notifications service...
Jul 10 09:40:38 aaron-lpt dbus-daemon[1520]: [session uid=1000 pid=1520] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.Notifications'
Jul 10 09:40:38 aaron-lpt systemd[1495]: Started XFCE notifications service.


grep -i notif ~/.xsession-errors
(nm-applet:1553): libnotify-WARNING **: 08:29:33.375: Failed to connect to proxy
(nm-applet:1553): nm-applet-WARNING **: 08:29:58.387: Failed to show notification: Error calling StartServiceByName for org.freedesktop.Notifications: Timeout was reached
** (pamac-tray:1558): WARNING **: 08:30:08.145: tray.vala:188: Error calling StartServiceByName for org.freedesktop.Notifications: Process org.freedesktop.Notifications exited with status 1
(nm-applet:1553): nm-applet-WARNING **: 08:30:58.198: Failed to show notification: Error calling StartServiceByName for org.freedesktop.Notifications: Timeout was reached
** (pamac-tray:1558): WARNING **: 09:29:37.675: tray.vala:214: Error calling StartServiceByName for org.freedesktop.Notifications: Timeout was reached
** (pamac-tray:1558): WARNING **: 09:30:13.136: tray.vala:188: Error calling StartServiceByName for org.freedesktop.Notifications: Process org.freedesktop.Notifications exited with status 1
(discord:9047): libnotify-WARNING **: 09:39:51.864: Failed to connect to proxy
(discord:9047): libnotify-WARNING **: 09:40:16.888: Failed to connect to proxy
[11204:11265:0710/094021.637904:ERROR:object_proxy.cc(632)] Failed to call method: org.freedesktop.Notifications.GetCapabilities: object_path= /org/freedesktop/Notifications: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NoReply: Did not receive a reply. Possible causes include: the remote application did not send a reply, the message bus security policy blocked the reply, the reply timeout expired, or the network connection was broken.
(discord:9047): libnotify-WARNING **: 09:40:27.138: Failed to connect to proxy
[10:02:25:416][0x1a18380][Info]components/core/event-count-notifier/AbstractEventCountNotifier.cpp:66: "Notify event count: 0."
[10:02:26:065][0x1a18380][Info]components/core/event-count-notifier/AbstractEventCountNotifier.cpp:66: "Notify event count: 0."
```

Answer (score 0):

What I have found that works for me according to the [manjaro forums](https://forum.manjaro.org/t/xfce4-notifyd-gtk3-the-notification-service-is-not-running-solved/60627/10)

```
systemctl --user start xfce4-notifyd
systemctl --user status xfce4-notifyd
systemctl --user enable xfce4-notifyd
```

But this was not a permanent fix for me.
It status changed from `linked` to `enabled`

```
systemctl --user status xfce4-notifyd
● xfce4-notifyd.service - XFCE notifications service
    Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/user/xfce4-notifyd.service; linked; vendor preset: enabled)
    Active: active (running) since Fri 2020-07-10 09:40:38 SAST; 52min ago
Main PID: 12585 (xfce4-notifyd)
    CGroup: /user.slice/user-1000.slice/user@1000.service/xfce4-notifyd.service
            └─12585 /usr/lib/xfce4/notifyd/xfce4-notifyd

Jul 10 09:40:38 aaron-lpt systemd[1495]: Starting XFCE notifications service...
Jul 10 09:40:38 aaron-lpt systemd[1495]: Started XFCE notifications service.

⟩ systemctl --user disable xfce4-notifyd
Removed /home/aaron/.config/systemd/user/xfce4-notifyd.service.

⟩ systemctl --user status xfce4-notifyd
● xfce4-notifyd.service - XFCE notifications service
    Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/user/xfce4-notifyd.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
    Active: active (running) since Fri 2020-07-10 09:40:38 SAST; 53min ago
Main PID: 12585 (xfce4-notifyd)
    CGroup: /user.slice/user-1000.slice/user@1000.service/xfce4-notifyd.service
            └─12585 /usr/lib/xfce4/notifyd/xfce4-notifyd

Jul 10 09:40:38 aaron-lpt systemd[1495]: Starting XFCE notifications service...
Jul 10 09:40:38 aaron-lpt systemd[1495]: Started XFCE notifications service.

⟩ systemctl --user enable xfce4-notifyd
Created symlink /home/aaron/.config/systemd/user/default.target.wants/xfce4-notifyd.service → /usr/lib/systemd/user/xfce4-notifyd.service.

⟩ systemctl --user status xfce4-notifyd
● xfce4-notifyd.service - XFCE notifications service
    Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/user/xfce4-notifyd.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
    Active: active (running) since Fri 2020-07-10 09:40:38 SAST; 53min ago
Main PID: 12585 (xfce4-notifyd)
    CGroup: /user.slice/user-1000.slice/user@1000.service/xfce4-notifyd.service
            └─12585 /usr/lib/xfce4/notifyd/xfce4-notifyd

Jul 10 09:40:38 aaron-lpt systemd[1495]: Starting XFCE notifications service...
Jul 10 09:40:38 aaron-lpt systemd[1495]: Started XFCE notifications service.
```